# how to create directory in mnt/sdcard in android 2.2

Tags: android

```
 File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File appPath = new File(exStoragePath + "/mbrc/");
            appPath.mkdirs();
            String tempFilename = "tmp.wav";
            String tempDestFile = appPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + tempFilename;

            return tempDestFile;
        }
```

I try this on HTC with Android 2.2 but directory is not created and file also not. If i try this on SAMSUNG S2 wuth android 4 then works.

Why this not working on HTC and android 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File appPath = new File(exStoragePath + "/mbrc/");
        appPath.mkdirs();
        String tempFilename = "tmp.wav";
        String tempDestFile = appPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + tempFilename;

        File newFile = new File(tempDestFile);
        newFile.createNewFile();

        return tempDestFile;
    }
```

Comment: Have you added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on manifest?